# Can't import data from excel file

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I am getting an error( Unparseable date: "18–11–2003") when i try to import data from excel file. the date from the file cannot be parsed

```
        if(row.getCell(16)!=null){
        String dobb=null;  
        Date dob=null;                            
        row.getCell(16).setCellType(row.getCell(16).CELL_TYPE_STRING);

         dobb=row.getCell(16).getStringCellValue();
         System.out.println(dobb);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    try {
         dob = (Date)simpleDateFormat.parse(dobb);//error..... Unparseable date: "18–11–2003"
        System.out.println("dateeee"+dob);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
                //dob=new Date();
}
```

Comment: Can u paste the console log .Are u sure the date coming from the excel is in dd-MM-yyyy format ?

Comment: yes...  i get d date lyk this   18–11–2003

Comment: 18–11–2003
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "18–11–2003"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the specified "18–11–2003" date contains `u2013` Unicode character instead of a normal dash which is `u002d`.

Here is a sample that uses the string copy-pasted from the question:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class TestDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        try {
            String trouble = "18–11–2003";
            String goodOne = "18-11-2003";
            Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(goodOne);
            //Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(trouble);
            System.out.println(String.format ("\\u%04x", (int)trouble.charAt(2)));
            System.out.println(String.format ("\\u%04x", (int)goodOne.charAt(2)));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The character in the actual date (`–`) is not the same character in your date format (`-`).

This code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println((int)'–');
    System.out.println((int)'-');
}
```

produces this result:

```
8211
45
```

There are several things you can do:

1. Do a `replace()` on your date string (`dateStr = dateStr.replace("–", "-");`) to replace the strange hyphen with an actual ASCII hyphen. ***Recommended***
2. Change your dateformat from `"dd–MM–yyyy"` to `"dd–MM–yyyy"`